# Does the neologism "knowlet" have correct morphology in English?

Tags: morphology, word-formation, neologism

I'm about creating a new word to denote small pieces of knowledge and understanding, like truthful sentences (eagles are birds), or informative news about technology (Google Chrome's market share beats IE).

Based on this argument, I chose the word **knowlet**:

1. Know means to *hold information in mind*, or *realize something*
2. *-let* is a suffix to denote smallness
3. Know + -let = knowlet (pronounced /nalet/)

Is it a correct neologism? What problems might it have?

Comment: It will become correct if a lot of people decide it is. That's how language evolves :) I can think of islet (small island), which is an accepted word (according to my spell-checker).

Comment: Please! "Islet" is isle + -et. There is no suffix "-let" in English.

Comment: @fdb Sure there is: [OED 1](http://archive.org/stream/oed6aarch#page/n229/mode/2up), s.v. **-let**. *Bracelet*, *frontlet*, *starlet* ...

Comment: You are aware of "factlet"? Maybe you wish to avoid the connotation of triviality?

Comment: @fdb - _Booklet_ and _leaflet_ are also examples of "-let" being a suffix in English.

Comment: Fair enough, but you agree with me about "islet" I trust. Etymologically, diminutive “-let” seems to derive from a false division of words like Old French chapel-et. But I accept that it has become a productive suffix in modern English, of course.

Comment: Tons of bit of language change in perfectly accepted words like *orange* and *pea* can be traced to misanalyses (if that's a word?) in tons of languages, so doubtless tons and tons more have been lost in the ancient history of a large proportion of modern words.

Comment: I don't know of any terms off the top of my head in English built by adding the suffix *-let* onto a verb though. But even so that wouldn't make it correct or incorrect, just attested or unattested.

Comment: @hippietrail It suggests that part of a native speaker's knowledge of productive derivational morphology includes the rule that the diminutive suffice *-let* combines with nouns, not verbs, i guess. *knowlet* certainly sounds bad to me, in a way that, for example, *factlet* doesn't, despite the fact i've never encountered either before, to my knowledge.

Comment: Yes especially given that the OP doesn't seem to be a native English speaker it seems we're being to nitpicky with "correct" and should read it as "Would this word formation be in accordance with English morphology?" etc. It is innovating by adding *-let* to a verb, but neologisms don't have to make morphological innovations. There are probably far more neologisms built using conservative/normal morphology.

Comment: @hippietrail Agreed. It's an interesting question whether these kinds of rules should be considered part of the grammar proper, i.e. whether or not 'knowlet' should be considered 'ungrammatical', broadly speaking. It seems to me that neologisms are pretty much *always* coined in accordance with productive morphological rules. I can't think of any exceptions.

Comment: @PElliott: When I thought about neologisms formed outside normal productive mophological rules, the first thing that popped into my head was the class of "portmanteu words" where to or possibly more words are consciously "blended" together to form a new word.

Comment: @hippietrail Oh yeah! I hadn't considered those. I actually have no idea what the rules are governing portmanteu formation in English. I'd tentatively guess that it's more phonologically conditioned than anything else. That would make a nice SE question.

Comment: 'knowlet' does not sound like a natural neologism to me. You might want to ask this at ELU for more perspective.

Comment: @Mitch: Indeed I think there's no intuitive way to pronounce "knowlet". Both "know let" and "nollet" are plausible but sound a bit "wrong". It would surely work as a trademark and have half the people pronounce it each way.

Comment: "Knowlet" is neologism but has already appeared in some places such as [this research paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2441475/).

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a "correctly-formed neologism".

Neologisms are, by definition, new, and therefore not provided for in The Rules.
So they're by definition also "incorrect".

Of course, The Rules can change, and that's what happens when a neologism survives.
The Rules come to accept it (or at least they ignore it).

As to "knowlet", there is a fundamental problem, caused, as usual, by English spelling.
The root *know* occurs with two pronunciations, though the spelling doesn't change:

- /no/, like the verb /noz/ in *He knows everything.*
- /na/, like the noun /'nalɪdʒ/ in *His knowledge is vast.*

So for any neologism spelled *knowlet*  -- never mind what it sposta mean --
it **could** be pronounced /'nolɪt/, like the verb,
or it could **also** be pronounced /'nalɪt/, like the noun.
(There is no hope, by the way, of getting the final syllable stressed, with this spelling)

If it were ever to become common, there would undoubtedly be some difference
in  pronunciation, because *knowlet* would occur almost exclusively in text.
So there would be phonological dialects from the beginning, and that leads
almost inevitably to semantic and syntactic dialects as well.

Comment: First of all, on this side of the Atlantic, at least, we say [nɔlɪdʒ], not [nɑlidʒ], so the difference between this and [nəʊ] is not very great. Second, and more to the point, neologisms conform to pre-established structures. Otherwise they would not be understood.

Comment: As this one isn't.

Comment: @fdb: `ɔ`? Are you sure? On my side of the Pacific it's `nɒlɪdʒ`. `ɔ` is the sound in "caught" and `ɒ` is the sound in "cot". It's well known that many parts of North America have undergone a cot-caught merger. I'm not an expert on British pronunciation though so you might be right. I know British has `/ɔkʃən/` where Australian has `/ɒkʃən/` for instance though I can't recall hearing "knowledge" with `/ɔ/` even by RP speakers.

Comment: @hippietrail: I use /a/ for American [ɒ], and I distinguish /a/ from /ɔ/ natively; I'm from Illinois.

Comment: @jlawler: British and Australian English each have three different vowels, `ɔ` as in "caught" and "border", `ɒ` as in "cot" and "bother", and `ɑ` as in "cart" and "father". The first and third are usually written in IPA with the long vowel mark. Not all American varieties have the cot-caught merger and then the differenc between rhotic and non-rhotic accents helps make it even murkier.

Comment: Yes, [nɒlɪdʒ] is what most people say on this little island.

Comment: Yes, I learned that RP distinguishes three low back vowels where I have only two. But I do have those two, which people on the US W. coast don't.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think this is a correctly formed neologism. The suffix -let forms diminutives from nouns. Or can you mention any verb+let formations? The other question is whether there is any need for such a word. What is actually wrong with "fact"?

Comment: Or if it doesn't like fact, there is factlet :)

Comment: Fact sounds cool. But what I want is to denote smallness of the information, which is not apparent and explicit in fact. I'd be grateful if you could suggest other terms. Smallness matters here.

Comment: Most facts are "small" too.